# Sharepoint 2010 login layout page gives Access denied error

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have few login screen in Loayout folder of sharepoint. When we are redirecting to change password screen it gives Access denied error. But no in other pages like Custom login page security question pages. In the debug mode also we couldnt get any error.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the whole access denied string. If you look at the parameters, you often can find the culprit or file in questions generating the access denied. Maybe you can post the whole URL when you get the access denied?